# How to factorize this polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, factoring

Polynomial to factorise :
$$ 2x^2 + y^2 - 3y = 0 $$

This is what I did but couldn't reach the final factors:
$$\ 2x^2 - 2 + y^2 - 3y + 2 = 0 $$
$$\ 2(x-1)(x+1) + (y-2)(y-1) = 0 $$

Now can we infer anything about the factors from the last expression?
If not, then what should be the initial way of factorising it?

Comment: Why do you think there is a factorization?

Comment: What is the context?

Comment: This is an auxilary equation of a partial differential equation which is to be factored.

Comment: Perhaps if you edited in the whole context we could help?

Comment: Maybe you're after something like $\left(x+\sqrt{\frac{3y-y^2}{2}}\right)\left(x-\sqrt{\frac{3y-y^2}{2}}\right)=0$?

Comment: Or inspired by @Shuri2060 $y=(3\pm\sqrt{9-8x^2})/2$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the verb is "to factor", not "to factorise"

Comment: As a polynomial over $\mathbf Q[x,y]$, it is irreducible by *Eisenstein criterion*.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, the equation describes the ellipse $$ \frac{4(y-3/2)^2}{18}+\frac{4x^2}{9}=1 $$ , so the zeros are exactly the set of points {$(x,y)$} in the ellipse described.